# How to delete duplicate records from a large table with partitions in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

We have a table with 6 partitions,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS asset
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    asset_name character varying(60) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    processing_status character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    source_system_id character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT asset_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, processing_status)
) PARTITION BY LIST (processing_status)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_processingstatus ON asset USING btree (processing_status COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_ops ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(processing_status)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_sourcesystemid ON asset USING btree (source_system_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_ops ASC NULLS LAST);

CREATE TABLE asset_processing PARTITION OF asset FOR VALUES IN ('processing');
CREATE TABLE asset_default PARTITION OF asset DEFAULT;
CREATE TABLE asset_np PARTITION OF asset FOR VALUES IN ('no processing');
CREATE TABLE asset_exc PARTITION OF asset FOR VALUES IN ('exception');
CREATE TABLE asset_execl PARTITION OF asset FOR VALUES IN ('exclusion');
CREATE TABLE asset_complete PARTITION OF asset FOR VALUES IN ('complete') PARTITION BY RANGE (id);
```

We are trying to delete duplicate records from the asset table for the year 2020 (there are total of 1,17,51,512 records for year 2020). We have written the following query for the same,

```
explain WITH CTE AS (SELECT id,created_at,ROW_NUMBER()
OVER(PARTITION BY source_system_id ORDER BY id desc) AS row_num FROM asset)
delete from asset where id in (select id from CTE as dups where dups.row_num > 1 AND extract(year from dups.created_at) = 2020)
```

however, the query is timing out due to poor performance with sequential scan on each partition and as the following query plan shows it is fetching more rows than we are expecting.

```
QUERY PLAN
Delete on asset  (cost=12145162.37..21224814.29 rows=40292652 width=34)
  Delete on asset_np
  Delete on asset_exc
  Delete on asset_execl
  Delete on asset_processing
  Delete on asset_complete_id0_1m
  Delete on asset_complete_id1_2m
  Delete on asset_complete_id2_3m
  Delete on asset_complete_id3_4m
  Delete on asset_complete_id4_5m
  Delete on asset_complete_id5_6m
  Delete on asset_complete_id6_7m
  Delete on asset_complete_id7_8m
  Delete on asset_complete_id8_9m
  Delete on asset_complete_id9_10m
  Delete on asset_complete_id10_max
  Delete on asset_default
  CTE cte
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=11137778.84..11540705.36 rows=80585303 width=45)
          ->  Sort  (cost=11137778.84..11178071.49 rows=80585303 width=37)
                Sort Key: asset_np_1.source_system_id, asset_np_1.id DESC
                ->  Append  (cost=0.00..7447352.86 rows=80585303 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_np asset_np_1  (cost=0.00..33704.43 rows=245809 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_exc asset_exc_1  (cost=0.00..18022.45 rows=91149 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_execl asset_execl_1  (cost=0.00..5148.16 rows=47719 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_processing asset_processing_1  (cost=0.00..1025945.41 rows=10305804 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id0_1m asset_complete_id0_1m_1  (cost=0.00..63448.94 rows=637312 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id1_2m asset_complete_id1_2m_1  (cost=0.00..64028.22 rows=642739 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id2_3m asset_complete_id2_3m_1  (cost=0.00..51541.67 rows=649890 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id3_4m asset_complete_id3_4m_1  (cost=0.00..42690.95 rows=651317 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id4_5m asset_complete_id4_5m_1  (cost=0.00..52737.41 rows=633136 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id5_6m asset_complete_id5_6m_1  (cost=0.00..60106.26 rows=610086 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id6_7m asset_complete_id6_7m_1  (cost=0.00..55862.26 rows=573087 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id7_8m asset_complete_id7_8m_1  (cost=0.00..56280.83 rows=576943 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id8_9m asset_complete_id8_9m_1  (cost=0.00..91081.03 rows=842676 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id9_10m asset_complete_id9_10m_1  (cost=0.00..75711.64 rows=850548 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_complete_id10_max asset_complete_id10_max_1  (cost=0.00..2691965.86 rows=30689952 width=37)
                      ->  Seq Scan on asset_default asset_default_1  (cost=0.00..2938199.41 rows=32537136 width=37)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605253.83 rows=122904 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_np_pkey on asset_np  (cost=0.08..3.98 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605239.73 rows=45574 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_exc_pkey on asset_exc  (cost=0.08..3.91 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605153.63 rows=23860 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_execl_pkey on asset_execl  (cost=0.08..3.48 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605276.43 rows=5152902 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_processing_pkey on asset_processing  (cost=0.09..4.09 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605262.03 rows=318656 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id0_1m_pkey on asset_complete_id0_1m  (cost=0.08..4.02 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605262.03 rows=321370 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id1_2m_pkey on asset_complete_id1_2m  (cost=0.08..4.02 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605262.03 rows=324945 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id2_3m_pkey on asset_complete_id2_3m  (cost=0.08..4.02 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605262.03 rows=325658 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id3_4m_pkey on asset_complete_id3_4m  (cost=0.08..4.02 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605262.03 rows=316568 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id4_5m_pkey on asset_complete_id4_5m  (cost=0.08..4.02 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605260.03 rows=305043 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id5_6m_pkey on asset_complete_id5_6m  (cost=0.08..4.01 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605260.03 rows=286544 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id6_7m_pkey on asset_complete_id6_7m  (cost=0.08..4.01 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605260.03 rows=288472 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id7_8m_pkey on asset_complete_id7_8m  (cost=0.08..4.01 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605266.03 rows=421338 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id8_9m_pkey on asset_complete_id8_9m  (cost=0.08..4.04 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.01..605266.03 rows=425274 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id9_10m_pkey on asset_complete_id9_10m  (cost=0.08..4.04 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.04..605281.53 rows=15344976 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_complete_id10_max_pkey on asset_complete_id10_max  (cost=0.11..4.12 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=604457.04..605281.53 rows=16268568 width=34)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=604456.93..604457.53 rows=200 width=32)
              Group Key: dups.id
              ->  CTE Scan on cte dups  (cost=0.00..604389.77 rows=134309 width=32)
                    Filter: ((row_num > 1) AND (date_part('year'::text, created_at) = '2020'::double precision))
        ->  Index Scan using asset_default_pkey on asset_default  (cost=0.11..4.12 rows=1 width=10)
              Index Cond: (id = dups.id)
```

how should we structure the query to execute it correctly while maintaining performance.

Comment: What is the use of your index idx_processingstatus ? Partitions each have only one value for this columns. So index has no use there.

Comment: extract(year from created_at) = 2020 is not efficient. I think it's way faster to use this : created_at>= '2020-01-01 00:00' and created_at< '2021-01-01 00:00'

Comment: Your query will delete all copies of the record when there's duplicates. Don't you want to keep one of them ?

Comment: Your first CREATE INDEX is not legal, as it include a column which doesn't exist.

Comment: Show the whole plan.  What can you expect us to do with that snippet?

Comment: This seems like a house-keeping task or a task for a maintenance window.  Why would such a task be run under a timeout in the first place?

Comment: @bokan what is the optimal way to re-write the query to retain the first of the duplicate entries (identified by id with least value)

Comment: If the row id is not part of what you consider duplicate, then it is ok. Otherwise, you can use the CID keyword to target one of the duplicate. There's a unique CID field for each row. It's the way Postgres internally identify rows. But if your ID are unique then it's ok.

Comment: You have to prevent duplicates in first place. In your case I would add a unique index per partition (create a template table, add the unique index to it, then use it as a model for partition). This way you could not have duplicates in the same partition. Then you can write a maintenance procedure that will match each partition with others. Since there's probably much less data in some of them, it will go faster.

You can add a unique index on the parent table, but since it must include the partition key, it will not prevent having duplicate with different status value.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, if you should not have duplicates, then avoid creating them.

It looks like this table is a list of tasks your application must process. I guess duplicates appear when several workers work on same task. To avoid it you must implement a proper queue using FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED. This is how a worker must pick a task waiting to be processed.

```
UPDATE tasks
SET    status = 'processing' 
WHERE  cid = (
         SELECT cid
         FROM   tasks
         WHERE  status = 'waiting'
         LIMIT  1
         FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
         )
RETURNING *;
```

This way you are sure a task won't be taken by two workers (or anything that lead to creating duplicates).

Then also make sure your table doesn't accept duplicates, you can add a trigger on insert that will prevent duplicates insertion.